# Check login data but dont login yet ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I want to check if the username and the password is correct. After that I am using my SMS Gateway which works fine.

The problem is that this code sample logs me in before I can use my SMS authentication. Can anyone help me? How can I check the username and password but not log the user in already?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToAction("SMSGateway", "Account");

        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");

        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });

        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Deine Anmeldedaten sind nicht korrekt. Versuche es nochmals.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different method. `SignInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync()`, this will check the provided password with the stored password in your `User` object.
If successful, the user will not be signed in.

Comment: Had the same idea but there i cant count the wrong attemps to logout the user after three wrong login attemps. Maybe the best thing would be to override the PasswordSignInAsync function and do something like remove the finall login and do it after the SMS verification